# Error de sintaxis al ejecutar una rutina en MySQL

Tags: mysql

```sql
BEGIN

declare totalProductos int;

declare totalCompras float;

declare totalVentas float;

declare ganancias float;

declare productosPocoStock int;

declare ventasHoy float;

SET totalProductos = (SELECT count(*) FROM productos p);

SET totalCompras = (SELECT sum(p.precio_compra_producto*p.stock_producto) FROM productos p);

SET totalVentas = (SELECT sum(vc.total_venta) FROM venta_cabecera vc);

SET ganancias = (SELECT sum(vd.total_venta) - sum(p.precio_compra_producto * vd.cantidad) FROM venta_detalle vd inner join productos p on vd.codigo_producto * p.codigo_producto);

SET productosPocoStock = (SELECT count(1) FROM productos p WHERE p.stock_producto <= p.minimo_stock_producto);

SET ventasHoy = (SELECT sum(vc.total_venta) FROM venta_cabecera vc WHERE vc.fecha_venta * curdate()); 


SELECT IFNULL(totalProductos,0) AS totalProductos,
       IFNULL(ROUND(totalCompras,2),0) AS totalCompras,
       IFNULL(ROUND(totalVentas,2),0) AS totalVentas,
       IFNULL(ROUND(ganancias,2),0) AS ganancias,
       IFNULL(productosPocoStock,0) AS productosPocoStock,
       IFNULL(ROUND(ventasHoy,2),0) AS ventasHoy;
END
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola, aunque el titulo puede dar una breve descripcion del problema, creo que a tu dida le falta un poco mas de contexto; por ejemplo decir cual es el error de sintaxis reportado, lo intentaste ejecutar en mysql?

Comment: po otro lado me gustaria saber que tiene que ver tu post con php...

Comment: el primer error que encontre en tu sentencia es este: `vd.codigo_producto * p.codigo_producto` por que usas el `*` ???

Comment: En cuanto a los `SET`: nunca está demás leer la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), por cierto.